# Database.Designer.cs not taking changes from Designer mode (Entity Framework)

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am working on a complex project that does not allow me to do a simple 'update model from database'. I have added a column to a table we have called `ContactPhoneNumbers` the catch here is that we have over 100 different versions of it all with different schemas for different companies (hence why I can't update my model from the db). I created a script and successfully added the new columd `Extension` to each table. I am manually trying to add the column in to the .csdl, .msl, and .ssdl files as well as adding them to the designer and designer.cs code behind files. I keep getting an error saying

**The Column 'Extension' specified as part of this MSL does not exist in MetadataWorkspace.**

I have manually added the column to all required areas of each .xxdl file mentioned above and added it to the code behind file of the designer but each time I hit save the constructor in the designer.cs file erases the manual line I place to set the Extension column

This

```
 public static ContactPhoneNumber CreateContactPhoneNumber(global::System.Guid contactPhoneNumberId, global::System.Guid contactId, global::System.String phoneNumber, global::System.String phoneNumberType, global::System.String extension)
    {
        ContactPhoneNumber contactPhoneNumber = new ContactPhoneNumber();
        contactPhoneNumber.ContactPhoneNumberId = contactPhoneNumberId;
        contactPhoneNumber.ContactId = contactId;
        contactPhoneNumber.PhoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        contactPhoneNumber.PhoneNumberType = phoneNumberType;
        contactPhoneNumber.Extension = extension;
        return contactPhoneNumber;
    }
```

Turns into this

```
public static ContactPhoneNumber CreateContactPhoneNumber(global::System.Guid contactPhoneNumberId, global::System.Guid contactId, global::System.String phoneNumber, global::System.String phoneNumberType)
    {
        ContactPhoneNumber contactPhoneNumber = new ContactPhoneNumber();
        contactPhoneNumber.ContactPhoneNumberId = contactPhoneNumberId;
        contactPhoneNumber.ContactId = contactId;
        contactPhoneNumber.PhoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        contactPhoneNumber.PhoneNumberType = phoneNumberType;
        return contactPhoneNumber;
    }
```

I think this is why I am getting this error since I believe the designer file is what takes care of the metadataworkspace. Here is my designer file (which never changes)

[image]

**How can I get my Object Model to match my conceptual, storage, and mapping models manually?**

Answer (score 0):

Found the fix. IT seems this is a finicky process. In order to get my changes to be picked up by the project I had to deleted my csdl and msl files from the web prokect/bin and the app_data folder. After that it was imperative to immediately clean and rebuild the solution.